# Is there an event for agrid cell (paste) when double clicked

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When an ag-grid cell is double-clicked to paste (ctrl + V )   some data,
I want that event (paste), but am not able to get the event for the cell

I tried onProcessCellFromClipboard for that particular cell , but that's also not firing

```
  columnDefs: [
   {
      field: 'name',
      headerName: 'name',
      width: 175,
      includeInSearch: true,
      suppressSorting: true,
      suppressFilter: true,
      suppressMenu: true,
      onProcessCellFromClipboard : (params) = > {
         //expecting this event to be fired when we do ctrl+v but not working
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can use all of the predefined JavaScript events to handle user inputs

Here are two functions that solved my life all the times : oninput and onchange

if you want to use them in angular you can have it in your template as :

```
<component (input)='youFunction()' (change)='yourSecondFunction()'></component>
```

For your case while using the AG-Grid there are several custom event either for columns or for cells :

For example for cell edition : the `cellValueChanged`, cellEditingeStarted, and cellEditingStopped functions can be overridden such as:

In your columnDef add this :

```
onCellValueChanged : this.YourOnCellValueChanged ,
onCellEditingStarted: this.thePasteStart,
onCellEditingStopped: this.thePasteEnd,
```

And in your script add a reference to the function

```
function  YourOnCellValueChanged (params) {
  console.log('The column has been changed '+ params);
}

function thePasteStart(event){
    console.log("Paste started "+ event.value)

}
function thePasteEnd(event){
    console.log("Paste Ended "+ event.value)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I want to catch the Ctrl + v clipboard event which I can't for now using any ag-grid event.

Comment: I don't think there's something else to trigger it using ag-grid